# Which linux version supports node js on windows 7

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

I am a windows 7 user and want to download npm and nodejs.
I have tried to install node js on windows 7 but it is not supported.
So, is there any linux version that can be downloaded on windows 7 and supports npm and nodejs ?
Or if anyone can tell any other way to download npm and nodejs on my pc.

And, I cannot upgrade my operating system.

Comment: You want to run a Linux ELF binary on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused, Linux cannot be installed on Windows (there's the subsystem on Windows 10, but that's different), as Linux is a kernel that is usually paired with the GNU operating system, in practice, this means Linux is used as an operating system, and cannot be installed on Windows.

Installing Linux on your computer would mean deleting Windows.

What you can do, if you can't uninstall Windows, is create a virtual machine running Debian (a popular Linux distribution) using VirtualBox, you'd need to get a [Debian ISO](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst) and create a virtual machine with it.

Once you install it, you can run `sudo apt install npm nodejs` inside a terminal to install Node.js and npm.

You don't have to use Debian, I suggested it because I personally like it for servers, but you can use Ubuntu, Fedora, Manjaro or any other distribution.

EDIT:

I did some further reading and found [this tutorial](https://www.centennialsoftwaresolutions.com/post/install-node-js-on-windows-7), in which is shown how to install Node.js on Windows 7, by installing the LTS release 13.14.0.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much. It worked perfectly and npm commands are also working. Installed 13.14.0.